# Thousands of visits from Huawei ASN, Singapore. Should I worry about them?

Tags: googlebot, web-crawlers, scraper-sites

I've got a website with information I do not want to be replicated.

I'm browsing my visits, and found thousands of visits per day from AS136907, an ASN of Huawei, Singapore. Always with similar IP addresses.

I do not know if such visitors are human real ones, or they are bots crawling my site with hidden intentions.

Any similar experience is welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious next step is to look through your log files and ascertain the following -

- Timing of requests
- Number of IP addresses involved
- What was being looked at by each IP address.
  " The REFERER string(s) used.
- The URL(s) viewed

Based on this you should be able to get more of a sense of what is going on and the scope of it and allow you to more reasonably postulate a hypotheses as to if its a bot (based on REFERER, timing, content taken) or real humans and an indication of what they were doing.

There is something else worth pointing out here - as a system administrator I know that I largely can't control who gets to look at public content on my site, and I need to be more concerned as to how I restrict, log and manage confidential content.

Comment: Found https://www.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/news/20200515115021810.html - Huawei Cloud appears to be focussed as IaaS (ala Amazon Web Services) targeted at governments in Asia.  This knowledge might inform your log analysis.

Answer (score 0):

So obvious it need not be mentioned in fact.
The simple answer is that this is not a human, it is a spider, so it may be caching your data, but that's what Google does anyway.
If you wish to block it from your servers then that is fine.
If you just wish to remove it from your stats, which is the actual issue, then that is fine too.

Comment: It sounds to me like the asker has information on their site that they don't want to be copied by bots, so only removing those visits from stats might not solve the actual issue.